# What does draft.js's output look like?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

Where can I find example of draft.js's output? I would like to find example of output with added images, mentions etc. to the editor. I mean that string as output which should be stored to database.

Comment: @AKX, I am using vue.js. I am not familiar with react.js. I want to know how this is implemented in draft.js to get some good idea for my editor based on vue.js.

Answer (score 0):

The [Flow typing](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/src/model/encoding/RawDraftContentState.js) is in here, replicated below.

```
export type RawDraftContentState = {
  blocks: Array<RawDraftContentBlock>,
  entityMap: {[key: string]: RawDraftEntity, ...},
};

export type RawDraftContentBlock = {
  key: ?string,
  type: DraftBlockType,
  text: string,
  depth: ?number,
  inlineStyleRanges: ?Array<InlineStyleRange>,
  entityRanges: ?Array<EntityRange>,
  data?: Object,
  children?: Array<RawDraftContentBlock>,
  ...
};

export type RawDraftEntity = {
  type: DraftEntityType,
  mutability: DraftEntityMutability,
  data: ?{[key: string]: any, ...},
  ...
};
```

Comment: Do I understand right that draft.js return `RawDraftContentState` object which can be saved to database as json?